# Where has the Object Index from Layers has been moved to in 2.80?

Tags: rendering, compositing-nodes

I need to use the Object Index for a couple of objects. But as seen in the image below, it is no longer found in the Layers/Passes window.

Thanks guys!

[image]

[image]

Comment: Suggest using *Cryptomatte* feature.

Comment: [Here's a link to the Blender manual's explanation of the Cryptomatte Node.](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/compositing/types/matte/cryptomatte.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to change from EEVEE to Cycles render in order to have that option[image]

Good Luck